# Parse content from tag referred by IDREF in XML file

Tags: xml, xslt

So, I have my XML file and I'm trying to retrieve a DropPoint's Designation for each DropPoint on a Reservation in order to place it on my tabel. The DropPoint field in every reservation is refered by an IDREF.

Is there any way to parse the designation onto my tabel without saving the id and iterating all DropPoints to find out which one im dealing with ?

Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<System xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:/Users/ASUS/Documents/lprog-xml/Reservations.xsd">
    <Reservations>
        <Reservation id="b1">
            <CourierToken>abb456fb</CourierToken>
            <CustomerToken>fsdg432n</CustomerToken>
            <BeginDate>
                <Calendar type="Gregorian">
                    <day>12</day>
                    <month>12</month>
                    <year>2016</year>
                </Calendar>
            </BeginDate>
            <Term>20</Term>
            <DropPoint id="f33"/>
            <Customer>
                <Username>pms</Username>
                <Password>sdasda</Password>
                <FirstName>Pedro</FirstName>
                <LastName>Pinto</LastName>
                <Email>xmllover4everAndEver64cm@email.com</Email>
            </Customer>
        </Reservation>
        <Reservation id="a2">
            <CourierToken>dfsd43b2</CourierToken>
            <CustomerToken>f3hu32mu</CustomerToken>
            <BeginDate>
                <Calendar type="Gregorian">
                    <day>13</day>
                    <month>January</month>
                    <year>2017</year>
                </Calendar>
            </BeginDate>
            <Term>5</Term>
            <DropPoint id="f33"/>
            <Customer>
                <Username>xss</Username>
                <Password>asdq</Password>
                <FirstName>Xavier</FirstName>
                <LastName>Silva</LastName>
                <Email>theincredibleone@email.com</Email>
            </Customer>
        </Reservation>
        <Reservation id="a342">
            <CourierToken>d4fd43b2</CourierToken>
            <CustomerToken>f3htg2mu</CustomerToken>
            <BeginDate>
                <Calendar type="Gregorian">
                    <day>10</day>
                    <month>March</month>
                    <year>2016</year>
                </Calendar>
            </BeginDate>
            <Term>45</Term>
            <DropPoint id="f33"/>
            <Customer>
                <Username>xss</Username>
                <Password>asdq</Password>
                <FirstName>Xavier</FirstName>
                <LastName>Silva</LastName>
                <Email>theincredibleone@email.com</Email>
            </Customer>
        </Reservation>
        <Reservation id="b3">
            <CourierToken>desfg236</CourierToken>
            <CustomerToken>43jmfh23</CustomerToken>
            <BeginDate>
                <Calendar type="Gregorian">
                    <day>1</day>
                    <month>January</month>
                    <year>2017</year>
                </Calendar>
            </BeginDate>
            <Term>8</Term>
            <DropPoint id="g34"/>
            <Customer>
                <Username>dal</Username>
                <Password>dasdg</Password>
                <FirstName>Daniel</FirstName>
                <LastName>Almeida</LastName>
                <Email>dokkanBattleFTW@email.com</Email>
            </Customer>
        </Reservation>
        <Reservation id="a56">
            <CourierToken>5bh4fdsf</CourierToken>
            <CustomerToken>onfdsn43</CustomerToken>
            <BeginDate>
                <Calendar type="Gregorian">
                    <day>23</day>
                    <month>9</month>
                    <year>2018</year>
                </Calendar>
            </BeginDate>
            <Term>15</Term>
            <DropPoint id="f33"/>
            <Customer>
                <Username>pops</Username>
                <Password>iHack</Password>
                <FirstName>Migas</FirstName>
                <LastName>what</LastName>
                <Email>getHackedM8@rekt.com</Email>
            </Customer>
        </Reservation>
        <Reservation id="t345">
            <CourierToken>432njdas</CourierToken>
            <CustomerToken>efg234jn</CustomerToken>
            <BeginDate>
                <Calendar type="Gregorian">
                    <day>25</day>
                    <month>11</month>
                    <year>2567</year>
                </Calendar>
            </BeginDate>
            <Term>56</Term>
            <DropPoint id="f33"/>
            <Customer>
                <Username>SenorJobs</Username>
                <Password>gr8b8m8ir88/8</Password>
                <FirstName>Steve</FirstName>
                <LastName>Jobs</LastName>
                <Email>iOwnAppleBitches@email.com</Email>
            </Customer>
        </Reservation>
        <Reservation id="p45">
            <CourierToken>acw4tsca</CourierToken>
            <CustomerToken>ascfdv32</CustomerToken>
            <BeginDate>
                <Calendar type="Gregorian">
                    <day>19</day>
                    <month>5</month>
                    <year>2020</year>
                </Calendar>
            </BeginDate>
            <Term>7</Term>
            <DropPoint id="f33"/>
            <Customer>
                <Username>SenorGates</Username>
                <Password>VivaLaMicrosoft</Password>
                <FirstName>Billy</FirstName>
                <LastName>Gator</LastName>
                <Email>cyaSteve@email.com.apple.pt</Email>
            </Customer>
        </Reservation>
        <Reservation id="df45">
            <CourierToken>34rfdf3d</CourierToken>
            <CustomerToken>554fgdvv</CustomerToken>
            <BeginDate>
                <Calendar type="Gregorian">
                    <day>21</day>
                    <month>10</month>
                    <year>2020</year>
                </Calendar>
            </BeginDate>
            <Term>20</Term>
            <DropPoint id="f33"/>
            <Customer>
                <Username>CristianoPenaldo</Username>
                <Password>saudadesIrina</Password>
                <FirstName>Cristiano</FirstName>
                <LastName>Ronaldo</LastName>
                <Email>esteMessiJaMeteNojo@email.com</Email>
            </Customer>
        </Reservation>
        <Reservation id="po454">
            <CourierToken>dfsg345d</CourierToken>
            <CustomerToken>sadfg345</CustomerToken>
            <BeginDate>
                <Calendar type="Gregorian">
                    <day>31</day>
                    <month>2</month>
                    <year>2345</year>
                </Calendar>
            </BeginDate>
            <Term>23</Term>
            <DropPoint id="f33"/>
            <Customer>
                <Username>ZLATAN</Username>
                <Password>iAmZlatan</Password>
                <FirstName>Zlatan</FirstName>
                <LastName>Ibrahimovic</LastName>
                <Email>rektByZlatan@email.com</Email>
            </Customer>
        </Reservation>
        <Reservation id="sd34">
            <CourierToken>34567asd</CourierToken>
            <CustomerToken>dssfdgh4</CustomerToken>
            <BeginDate>
                <Calendar type="Gregorian">
                    <day>10</day>
                    <month>10</month>
                    <year>2030</year>
                </Calendar>
            </BeginDate>
            <Term>4</Term>
            <DropPoint id="f33"/>
            <Customer>
                <Username>PashaBiceps</Username>
                <Password>maFriend</Password>
                <FirstName>Pasha</FirstName>
                <LastName>Biceps</LastName>
                <Email>youAreMyBrotherMyFriend@email.com</Email>
            </Customer>
        </Reservation>
    </Reservations>
    <DropPoints>
        <DropPoint id="f33">
            <Designation>Quinta das Freiras</Designation>
            <State>Free</State>
            <Location>
                <Street>Rio Tinto</Street>
                <ZipCode>4435-074</ZipCode>
                <Country>Portugal</Country>
                <Coordinates>
                    <Longitude>32</Longitude>
                    <Latitude>52</Latitude>
                </Coordinates>
            </Location>
        </DropPoint>
        <DropPoint id="g34">
            <Designation>Norte Shopping</Designation>
            <State>Free</State>
            <Location>
                <Street>Porto</Street>
                <ZipCode>4488</ZipCode>
                <Country>Portugal</Country>
                <Coordinates>
                    <Longitude>24</Longitude>
                    <Latitude>12</Latitude>
                </Coordinates>
            </Location>
        </DropPoint>
    </DropPoints>
</System>
```

And here is the XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="Designation" match="Designation" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="/System/Reservations/">
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Courier Token</th>
            <th>Customer Token</th>
            <th>Begin Date</th>
            <th>Term</th>
            <th>Drop Point</th>
            <th>Customer Username</th>
            <th>Customer First Name</th>
            <th>Customer Email</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="/System/Reservations/Reservation">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="CourierToken"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="CustomerToken"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="BeginDate/Calendar/day"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Term"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="key('Designation', @Designation)"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Customer/Username"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Customer/FirstName"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="Customer/Email"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up a key

```
<xsl:key name="drop-point" match="DropPoints/DropPoint" use="@id">
```

then when processing a `Reservation` you can use `<xsl:value-of select="key('drop-point', DropPoint/@id)/Designation"/>` to output the `Designation` of the referenced `DropPoint`.

Also note that `<xsl:template match="/System/Reservations/">` should be `<xsl:template match="/System/Reservations">`, without the trailing `/`.